# JPA EclipseLink entities not refreshing

Tags: jsf, jpa, eclipselink

I have a problem with entities not being refreshed when values in the database are changed from outside the JPA session. For instance, I have a user entity:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver")
    @JoinTable(name = "NOTIFICATIONS_RECEIVED")
    private List<NotificationBean> notificationsReceived;
    ...

}
```

And notifications entity:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable(false)
public class NotificationBean implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private UserBean receiver;
    ...

}
```

I use this inside a JSF application and have a SessionScoped bean, which loads the user after login and stores it:

```
@Named("sessionManager")
@SessionScoped
public class SessionManagerBean implements Serializable {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "PU")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    private UserBean user;

    public UserBean getUser() throws Exception {
        if (user == null) {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
            String username = request.getRemoteUser();
            if (username != null) {
                EntityManager em = null;
                try {
                    utx.begin();
                    em = emf.createEntityManager();
                    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u from UserBean u WHERE u.username = ?1");
                    query.setParameter(1, username);
                    user = (UserBean) query.getSingleResult();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    try {
                        utx.rollback();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    } finally {
                    utx.commit();
                    em.close();
                    }
                }
                return user;
            }
        }
    }

    public void refreshUser() {
         EnitytManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
         // similar code as above to retrieve the user from the database
         em.refresh(user);
    }
}
```

The page which displays the notifications calls `refreshUser()` when it loads:

```
<f:metadata>
   <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{sessionManager.refreshUser()}" />
</f:metadata>
```

The user data is not refreshed though and notifications which are displayed on the page are not updated when I refresh the page.

However, if I change `refreshUser()` to:

```
public void refreshUser() {
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        List<NotificationBean> notifications = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM NOTIFICATIONBEAN WHERE RECEIVER_ID = " +
               user.getId() + ";").getResultList();
        user.setMatchChallengesReceived(notifications);
}
```

the notifications are updated.

I have more variable than notifications that I need to refresh from the database and it would be a lot of code to do the same for each one. I thought `em.refresh(user)` should reload all variables that have changed from the database for me. I thought it is a caching issue, so I added `@Cacheable(false)` to `UserBean` and `NotificationBean`, but it has no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem is with notifications, then itis because refreshing user is not set to cascade the refresh.   Set the CascadeType.REFRESH on the notificationsReceived mapping.

Comment: In UserBean I changed 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver") to 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "receiver", cascade = "CascadeType.REFRESH"), but it has no effect. Any other ideas?

Comment: Now you need to call em.refresh(user), or add the "eclipselink.refresh" query hint to the query bringing in user: query.setHint("eclipselink.refresh", true);

Comment: Sorry, I forgot t mention that I changed refreshUser back to:
    public void refreshUser(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.refresh(em.merge(user));
    }
And now I see what the error was. If I put only em.refresh(user), I would get an error that user is not managed by the EntityManager, so I added merge(user) to fix that, but that didn't work correctly, I think the merge overwrote all changes that have been done to the user externally. Now I re-associate user with the EM as:

Comment: user = em.find(user.getClass(), user.getId());
and then refresh with:
em.refresh(user);
Thanks for your help!